# jQuery - using promise().done() more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I've been trying to do this tonight and I can't seem to finish it. I've got something I'm developing that has a 'menu', of sorts - for example: on a click of the back button, one submenu fades out and the other fades back in. But I'm having a bit of trouble with this; when I use a normal callback function the main menu fades back in before the submenu is finished fading out. If I use `promise().done()`, then it won't fire more than once (from what I get). I open the submenu, then hit the back button. The submenu fades out and nothing else happens. Help?

```
$('#newgame').click(function() {
    $('#menu').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#newgameoptions').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
$('.back').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(1000);
});
$('.submenu').promise().done(function() {
    $('#menu').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: You'll need to post or link to your code.

Comment: Can't help you very specifically without seeing your code.  A normal callback function for a jQuery animation works just fine if you are using it correctly.  Or, promises can provide similar functionality.

Comment: look http://jsfiddle.net/RGZv3/ it's suppose to work

Comment: Promises only resolve _once_, they are one time.

Comment: Triad and jfriend, I edited the post to include my code. Also, the callback *without* the promise shows the previous menu for about a second even when the main one is faded fully in. (it's firing before the other animation is complete). @BenjaminGruenbaum, does that mean it is not possible to fix my problem?

Comment: @user3225645 see Bergi's solution. It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new promise for every submenu fading out, i.e. move it into the handler:

```
$('.back').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function() {
        $('#menu').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Or, without `.promise()`, you would just use the usual `callback` argument to the `fadeOut` method, like you have done it in the `$('#menu').fadeOut()` already:

```
$('.back').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#menu').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```